# Displaying an image from a folder on an aspx webpage (VB)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have my web-page set up to display categories, products, product names, etc from a Database using VB like so:

```
Web page:
<asp:label id="lblCategoryName" runat="server" text ="Label"></asp:label>
```

```
Web page.vb:
 If Request.QueryString("MainCategoryID") <> "" Then
            lblCategoryName.Text = Request.QueryString("MainCategoryName")
            Label1.Text = Request.QueryString("MainCategoryName")
            SqlDSSubCategory.SelectCommand = "Select * From Category Where Parent = " & CInt(Request.QueryString("MainCategoryID"))
            SqlDSSubCategory.DataBind()
```

My question is if/how to display an image on the web page from a folder controlled by a DB table value without saving the path onto the database.

For example could I do something like

```
<img id="product-image"  src='img/product/<% Eval("MainCategoryName") %>.jpg' alt"">
```

with the file stored in `img/preview/product/` saved as the respective MainCategoryName.jpg?

Comment: You are on the right track. But the `img` tag has to be associated with (inside) a gridview or *something* with a datasource. That way the `Eval` will read data-values.

Comment: @wazz
If I contained ```<img>``` within ```<asp:Image ConnectionString="MyDatabase">``` would that work then?

Comment: I think I missed the point. First make sure you can get the data you want from the db or query string. Is that working? When you have the data for 'MainCategoryName'  you can just set the source on an asp:Image control. But, no, you can't just set the value and it will come out of a db; you have to get the value in code and apply it.